# SimGrid: How check Host is executing task or not?

Tags: java, simgrid

In MasterWorker simulation, is there any method for Master to check whether Host of Worker is executing task now or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest seems to check the load of the machine with host.getHost().

Another solution would be to retrieve the cpu resource of your host, and check isUsed(). But you are not supposed to access the cpu directly so checking the load is better.

Comment: If Host is off, getLoad returns "0" or `none`?

Comment: It seems to be that Host().getLoad is not implemented.

Answer (score 2):

The question is unclear. Do you want to know whether the machine (Host) or process (Worker) is busy doing something?

For the worker, you're in the Java world. Adding a "boolean busy" field and its set/get functions could do the trick. When the worker starts to execute a task, it sets this boolean (for itself or its host) to true, and set it to false when done. Any other object in the simulation can call the getter to know what you're asking for.

For the host, something similar can be done but requires more efforts.

Comment: Could you, please, more verbosely describe the steps of second case? Do I have to change .xml files?

Comment: I guess there are the same actions in the second case. But what about platform.xml and deployment.xml?

Comment: If you just need to know whether a Host is busy or not, the easiest way I'm thinking of is to use the setProperty and getProperty methods of the Host class. Before starting to compute call setProperty("busy", "yes") and setProperty("busy", "no") when the task execution ends. The master can call getProperty("busy") for any host to know whether it's currently busy or not.